# Mastering Extjs user management unable to load Groups

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am currently following this book "Mastering Extjs" and I don't know why but I am unable to load the "Groups" store when viewing the user's information.

Only after viewing the Groups view and clicking on the Users view then I get to see the name of the group.

This is the codes that I call to replace "1" with "admin".

However it only loads "Admin" after I load the "Groups and Permissions" tab. Is there anyway I can load "admin" without clicking on the "groups and permissions" Tab?

```
width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'group_id',
            text: 'Group',
            renderer: function(value, metaData, record){
                var groupStore = Ext.getStore('groups');
                //console.log(groupStore);
                var group = groupStore.findRecord('id',value);
                //console.log(group);
                return group !=null ? group.get('name') : value;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the group store as `autoLoad: true`, then it gets loaded initially.

Alternatively, you can load it on demand :

```
var groupStore = Ext.getStore('groups');
if (!groupStore.isLoaded())
    groupStore.load();
groupStore.findRecord('id',value);
```

Comment: Why are you using count()? What if there are no groups? You load it again? Why not using isLoaded()? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-isLoaded